# Changing Menu Bar Font Size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using WordPress for a website.

Here is the link for the website: http://Jamezpearce.byethost7.com

How can I can make the font smaller so can fit more menu bars onto the website?

I really appreciate any help given to me if anyone wants anything else please comment and I will supply it.

I have already tried altering the CSS but don't seem to get anywhere I'm probably doing it incorrectly.

I have added

```
font-size: 0.75em;
```

to all the menu CSS I can see and still no joy.

```css
/* Pagenavi  */

#pnavigation {
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

.wp-pagenavi {
    font-size:0.75em;
    text-align: centre !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi a:link, .wp-pagenavi a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #42444e!important;
    border: 1px solid #212227!important;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 4px 8px !important;
    display: block;
    text-align: centre;
    float: centre;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size:0.75em;
}

.wp-pagenavi a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.pages {
    display: none;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.current {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #CF5912 !important;
    border: 1px solid #993206!important;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 4px 8px !important;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: centre;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size:0.75em;
}

.wp-pagenavi span.extend {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #FFD000 !important;
    border: 1px solid #E8B900 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 4px 8px !important;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: centre;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size:0.75em;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `#submenu li a {font-size: .75em;}`

Comment: No just add it as a separate ruleset.

Answer (score 2):

Try and change the `font-size`. You can change this in the `#botmenu` or in the `#submenu`

```
#botmenu {
    font-size: 90%; /*the smaller the percentage, the smaller the text*/
}
```

OR

```
#submenu {
    font-size: 90%; /*the smaller the percentage, the smaller the text*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `#submenu li a {font-size: .75em;}` doesnt work, try adding like this.

```
submenu li a {
     font-size: .75em !Important;
}
```

Comment: dont use important please. rather then use `submenu li a a {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `font-size: 100%`. The percentage is inherited from the parent, and you can also set 75% or 85%. I recommend you to play a bit in dev tools with this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Some 'coders' might have their opinion but for me I will add a new class with `!important`
eg;

`.wp-mbfontupdate {0.75em !important}`

Then add the `wp-mbfontupdate` class to my menubar's class. This way I can easily go to this line and update new font style later